# Truncate leading 1 in a hexadecimal value [C++]

Tags: hex, bit, truncate

How do I terminate the leading 1 in this hexadecimal value?

I want the hexadecimal output to read just "10" in this case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string string0 = "01";
    string string1 = "06";
    string string2 = "000B";
    string string3 = "00FE";
    int checkSum0 = stoi(string0, 0, 16);
    int checkSum1 = stoi(string1, 0, 16);
    int checkSum2 = stoi(string2, 0, 16);
    int checkSum3 = stoi(string3, 0, 16);
    int _checkSum = checkSum0 + checkSum1 + checkSum2 +checkSum3;

    
    cout << hex <<_checkSum << endl;
}
```